# javascript onclick counter initializes to 0 on refresh

Tags: javascript

I have a button in my JSP,

```
<input type="button" id="processItem" name="_eventId_submitButton" value="Submit" onclick="submitClick();buttonClick();"></input>
```

my javascript,

```
var clicks = 0;
 function submitClick(){
            var aButton = document.getElementById('submithidden');
            aButton.click();    
            return true;
        }        
     function buttonClick(){
         document.getElementById('clicked').value = ++clicks;
         }
```

this is where I am showing the counts of `submit`

```
    <tr><td><p>Total No of Scans<input type="text" id="clicked" size="3" 
onfocus="this.blur();" value="0" >.</p></td></tr>
```

everytime I click on submit, counter shows 1 and immediately the page refreshes and again it becomes 0. I want to keep it incremented untill the user leaves the page!

Comment: return false within the submitClick function to prevent the page from reloading (but you'll need to submit the data via ajax). Or use localStorage/sessionStorage/cookies to keep it for some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var clicks = 0;
 function submitClick(){
            var aButton = document.getElementById('submithidden');
            aButton.click();    
            return false;
        }        
     function buttonClick(){
         document.getElementById('clicked').value = ++clicks;
         }
```

False instead of true ;) 
the button "posts" the site, if you set false, i will not fire

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sessionStorage`  instead of storing in  js variable . It will be available until the browser is open .

```
sessionStorage.clicks = value;
```